# How to know the online status of raspberry pi in website and also reboot rpi by website over internet

Tags: php, raspberry-pi

How to know the online status of raspberry pi in website and also reboot rpi by website over internet.
i use php to create web console but how to know if the raspberry is connect.
i want to display in my website if the raspberry is online or not.
Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a python script in rpi and send continues data which will let you know the system is on.
And similary make an API and read the data from rpi to shutdown .
[https://codescracker.com/python/program/python-program-shutdown-restart-computer.htm#:~:text=To%20shutdown%20and%20restart%20your,shutdown%20your%20computer%20in%20python](https://codescracker.com/python/program/python-program-shutdown-restart-computer.htm#:%7E:text=To%20shutdown%20and%20restart%20your,shutdown%20your%20computer%20in%20python).

Comment: what data should i send continuously. like?can i get an example .Thanks

Comment: You can send any thing....so that you can know you are receiving data from the system.